# laravel Error "Call to undefined method stdClass::notify()" in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-8

i want to be able to send emails to user once i verify their account but i keep having this error "Call to undefined method stdClass::notify()" and i don't know where i'm wrong. please help me look at my code and tell me whats wrong.
this is my controller.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Admin;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;
use App\Notifications\AccountVerificationEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use Notifiable;

class UserController extends Controller
{   
 use \Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable; 
 use \Illuminate\Notifications\RoutesNotifications;
 public function update_verify($id){
         $post = User::first();
        $post = DB::table('users')
                ->select('submitted')
                ->where('id', '=' ,$id )
                ->first();

                if ($post->submitted == 0) {
                     $submitted = 1;
                }
                else{
                     $submitted = 0;
                }
                $val = array('submitted' => $submitted); 
            DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->update($val);

            $vermail =  DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
            $vermail->notify(new AccountVerificationEmail());        

         return redirect('verify')->with('success','User has been verified!');
   }
}
```

i tried using this "Notification::send($vermail , new AccountVerificationEmail());" in replace of "$vermail->notify(new AccountVerificationEmail());"  but i still got error

and this my notification page

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class AccountVerificationEmail extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    private $vermail;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($vermail)
    {
        $this->vermail = $vermail;//
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('Your account has been verified!')
                    ->action('Go to home page', url('/https://switfx.com/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

and lastly this is my user model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use \Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use \Illuminate\Notifications\RoutesNotifications;
 

class User extends Model
{
     use \Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use \Illuminate\Notifications\RoutesNotifications;
 
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using DB::table, which returns standard objects, instead of Eloquent, which adds all of the extra functionality. Change this line

```
$vermail =  DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
```

to

```
$vermail = User::find($id);
```